# Make div draggable across screen

Tags: jquery, html

I have a normal div with the attributes

```
div{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

That I want to be able to be dragged. By draggable, I mean: as long as your mouse is clicked onto the div, it follows your mouse, and when you let go of your mouse, it stays in the position you let it go at.

Thanks so much to anyone who can help!

http://jsfiddle.net/aritro33/k9DGH/

Comment: You can use jQuery UI's `draggable` or [make your own](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/draggable-without-jquery-ui/). This question does not show any attempts at a solution or research

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/k9DGH/9/

Have some JQuery (requires JQuery UI)
:

```
$('div').draggable();
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick and somewhat dirty solution goes something like the following:

Let's setup the html a little:

```
<div class='drag-container'>
    <div class='draggable'></div>
</div>
```

Here I wrap your div in another div, so that it could set `position:relative`. You could optionally set this on the `body`. You could set it inline, or in CSS, but it's probably more natural to do it in code instead.

```
var refx = 0, refy = 0, isdragging = false;
$(".drag-container").css("position", "relative");
$(".draggable").css({left:0, top:0})
  .on("mousedown", function(evt) {
    isdragging = true;
    var src = $(event.target).closest('.draggable');
    refx = evt.pageX - parseInt(src.css("left"));
    refy = evt.pageY - parseInt(src.css("top"));
}).on("mousemove", function(evt){
    if(!isdragging) return;
    var dx = evt.pageX - refx;
    var dy = evt.pageY - refy;
    console.log(dx, dy);
    $(event.target)
        .closest('.draggable')
        .css({left:dx + "px", top: dy + "px"});
}).on("mouseup mouseout click dbclick mousein", function(){
    isdragging = false;
});
```

The only weird bit here is many handlers for stopping the dragging. I've found that most of them are needed in some corner cases.

You can see the intended functionality in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9DGH/13/).